# Deleting multiple rows at once with Doctrine DBAL, is it possible?

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, silex, dbal

First of all, I just want to mention that this is not an "issue" at all. Deleting with Doctrine DBAL is not a problem and I am able to do it.

What I actually wanted to know is if there is way to delete multiple rows at once without have to loop for example an array.

For my project I use [Silex](http://silex.sensiolabs.org/) and the [Doctrine DBAL](http://doctrine-dbal.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/data-retrieval-and-manipulation.html)

**Here goes an example how I currently do it:**

```
$toDelete = array(1,2,3,4);

foreach($toDelete as $id){
   $this->app['db']->delete('table_name',array('id' => $id ));
}
```

Is there any approach to avoid the looping?

Comment: probably this helps: http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/batch-processing.html#bulk-deletes

Comment: DBAL supports WHERE id IN(?) with an array of ids: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/latest/reference/data-retrieval-and-manipulation.html#list-of-parameters-conversion

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use list of parameters: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/latest/reference/data-retrieval-and-manipulation.html#list-of-parameters-conversion

```
$connection->executeQuery('DELETE FROM table_name WHERE id IN (?)',
    array(array(1,2,3,4)),
    array(\Doctrine\DBAL\Connection::PARAM_INT_ARRAY)
);
```

or with query builder:

```
$builder = $connection->createQueryBuilder()
    ->delete('table_name')
    ->where('id in (:ids)')
    ->setParameter(':ids', array(array(1,2,3,4)), Connection::PARAM_INT_ARRAY);
$builder->execute();
```

Comment: `Expected 1 arguments. Found 0.` at `createQueryBuilder()`

Answer (score 1):

Not without writing your own query.

`$app["db"]` (assuming default silex/doctrine setup) is a doctrine connection, so you have the possibility to execute any query you want.